# Splitting multiband raster into multiple bands using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, ndvi

I'm using the ModelBuilder functionality in ArcGIS, and would like to take a raster that contains 4 bands, clip it with a polygon and then make NDVI from the clipped file. To do that, I need access to the different bands in the raster. In QGIS (where I'm coming from), some libraries don't preserve all 4 bands.

In QGIS, the raster calculator menu gave access to all of the bands, but ArcGIS doesn't seem to. Examples I've found breaks the raster into multiple entities in the model builder and works with those?

In ModelBuilder, how would you go about breaking the raster into its 4 bands?

Answer (score 2):

No need to export to single bands, there are a couple of ways of adding individual bands directly from the original multiband dataset:

- double click on the raster dataset in the file dialog.
- click on the + symbol next to the raster name in the Catalog window in ArcMap (or ArcCatalog). If you can't see any + symbols in the Catalog window  tree, click the Toggle Contents Panel button in the Catalog window toolbar.

If you want to be able to add the bands using the dropdown in the tool, you have to add the band individually to the ArcMap TOC, as per above, either using the Add Data button, or Catalog.

Comment: Or use Make Raster Layer tool and set band number in the appropriate parameter.

Comment: Yes indeed, I always forget that tool!

Comment: I'm trying to use Modelbuilder to make a model that seamlessly takes in a large raster, shape file to cut it with and make an NDVI from the cut raster. I'm at the NDVI step now, I would like to access the 4 bands from the raster in the model builder, is that possible?
Also, can the Make Raster Layer tool work in Model Builder? The NDVI function included with ArcGIS is a function and those are not supported in Model Builder.

Comment: Yes, select the individual bands as I described or use the 'Make Raster Layer' tool